# Why is high voltage lethal?

Tags: electric-current, voltage

Why is it that high voltage is lethally dangerous compared to low voltage with the same amount of current? How does current behave with low voltage and with high voltage? I have read many similar Q & As on this site but none of them had accurate and to the point answers to my question.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287571/calculating-electrical-shock-danger

Comment: The voltage across any two-terminal circuit element (e.g., a human body) and the current flowing through the circuit element are not independent variables. You can't arbitrarily change one without also changing the other. The relationship between them is different for different kinds of circuit element, but for a human body, Ohm's Law is approximately correct: When a circuit element element obeys Ohm's Law, that means that current and voltage always vary in direct proportion with each other, and the constant of proportionality is known as "resistance."

Answer (score 4):

The human body has a high, but non-infinite, electrical resistance (e.g., 1M ohms).  On a "first order" approximation, the human body also follows Ohm's Law, where $V=IR$.  If this equation is solved for current flow, the equation is $I=V/R$.

Obviously, for a fixed resistance, a higher voltage drop across a resistance results in a higher current through that resistor.  If a person becomes "grounded" against a high voltage source, and the resulting current runs through their heart, it only takes 10 milli-amps of current to severely disrupt their heart rhythm.

In addition to the above, it should be noted that high voltage is not necessarily "lethally dangerous".  If a person gets on an object that is at a high voltage, and that person is not "grounded", no current will flow through the person and no harm will come to him or her.  This can be seen every time a bird lands on a 12 kV distribution wire running through a neighborhood, and doesn't touch anything other than that wire.  It is the following combination of events that makes a given voltage lethal:

1) One part of a person's body is touching a high voltage source

2) Another part of that person's body is touching an object (e.g., the ground) that is at a much lower voltage than the high voltage source, and that second object completes a path for current to flow

3) The path of current flow through the person passes through the heart, and the magnitude of current is 10 milli-amps or higher

4) That person remains in contact with the high voltage source for an extended period of time

Comment: Some of your numbers don't line up with with IEC 60479-1 "Effects of current on human beings and livestock"  an international  IEC Technical Specification I am familiar with and used as guidance for many safety standards.  For example, according to it the threshold of ventricular fibrillation for continuous 50/60 Hz current is around 35 mA.  Also the skin impedance depends on the voltage (as well as skin conditions dry). Hand to hand body impedance at 10 V rms 50 Hz is in the range 5-6 K ohm for 50 % of the population.   At 100 vac its between 1500-2000 ohms.

Comment: I based my resistance measurements on a volt meter (DC current).  Also, I don't know if 10 mA will cause ventricular fibrillation, but I do distinctly remember that heart rhythm is affected at that point.

Comment: 50/50 Hz 10 mA current will not cause ventricular fibrillation, but it will cause muscle tetanization, or "inability to let go".